# Addthis share buttons inside bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis

I am having trouble getting the addThis buttons to show inside of a bootstrap popover. The code is in the html data attribute and the addThis script is firing correctly, but the buttons just don't show even though the code can be seen in it via inspector.

I've done a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XW9bk/1/

```
<li id="share" class="text-primary" data-html="true" data-content="<div class='addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style'><a class='addthis_button_preferred_1'></a><a class='addthis_button_preferred_2'></a><a class='addthis_button_preferred_3'></a><a class='addthis_button_preferred_4'></a><a class='addthis_button_compact'></a><a class='addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style'></a></div>" data-original-title="" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="right"><a class="text-success">Share</a></li>

$('#share').click(function() {
    $('.vote, .favorite, #share').popover('hide');
    $('#share').popover('toggle');
})

$(document).ready(function() {
    var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar": true};
    $.getScript("//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=imperium2335")
})
```

---

I've got it working in a way with:

```
$('#share').click(function() {
    $('.vote, .favorite').popover('hide');
    $('#share').popover('toggle');
    addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox');
})
```

The problem now is there is a delay of several seconds before the buttons are displayed in the popover. When the popover is hidden and then reopened, the buttons aren't there and again take a while to appear.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Try parsing the popover to <a> element instead of the <li>

Comment: @Tsalikidis Nothing happens at all when I do that, popover doesn't show :(.

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/XW9bk/5/

Comment: I changed the code a bit because I don't know what are you trying to do exactly but it doesn't seem right to hide and toggle the share popover at the same time. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/XW9bk/6/

Comment: What's addThis.toolbox? Is this a plugin or something? If you are getting buttons from a HTTP request then the delay is obvious

Comment: @Tsalikidis I thought that, but no requests show up in the inspector when I click it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a timing issue with the script loading, combined with the fact that it is essentially dynamic content. This will work for your situation:

HTML

```
<div class="hidden">
    <div class="the-content"></div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var addthis_config = {
        "data_track_addressbar": true
    };

    var theCode = '<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"><a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a><a class="addthis_button_compact"></a><a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a></div>';

    var theButton = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-placement="right" rel="popover">Popover on right</button>';

    $('.the-content').append(theCode).promise().done(function () {
        $.getScript("//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=imperium2335", function () {
            setTimeout(function() { $('body').append(theButton); }, 1000);
            $('body').popover({
                selector: '[rel=popover]',
                html: true,
                content: function () {
                    return $('.the-content').html();
                }

            });
        });
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XW9bk/8/)**

Comment: It is loading fine. But when click on icon its href is # always so it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what you were trying to do successfully, except that the problem was that share buttons were not clickable. Someone contacted AddThis support, this is the response they got;

> [Unfortunately without seeing it in action I can't diagnose the problem. If the buttons are visible but not clickable then there's either something hijacking the click action or another transparent element z-indexed over it.](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/1016249-addthis-order-of-operations)

I solved this problem by loading the AddThis buttons after the popover has been shown. See the code below;

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-artist-add-share has-popover" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="<div id='pcontent'></div>">Share <i class="fa fa-share padding-left-20"></i>
</button>

<script language="JavaScript">
  $("[rel=popover]").popover({
    html: true
  });

  $("[rel=popover]").on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    $('#pcontent').html("<div class='addthis_sharing_toolbox'></div>")
    $.getScript("//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4fa624772af11b1b")
  });
</script>
```